# Changes needed to schema.xml and solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr, configuration-files

I'm adding a few fields using solrj. What changes need i make in the solrconfig.xml and schema.xml?

I'm new to solr and i'd love some help

Comment: have you read http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml ?

Comment: If you explained the fields you've added.. and perhaps we could help you out.. Otherwise it's a case of reading the Wiki as mauricio said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to change solrconfig.xml unless you are changing the way your solr instance behaves.  Adding a field just requires that schema.xml include a line like:

```
<field name="myField" type="[field of a type defined in your schema]" indexed="true|false"  stored="true|false"  multiValued="true|false" />
```

Comment: I did that and I got an error - Unknown field.

Should I change any requestHandlers?

The code:

SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
     String docID = "1112211111";
     doc.addField( "id", docID, 1.0f );
     doc.addField( "name", "ESFDF", 1.0f );
     
     UpdateResponse upres = server.add( doc );

Comment: If you're getting an "Unknown field" then it is most likely that your incoming XML has a field that has not been declared in your schema.  Can you show us the <field> elements for your id and name fields?

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting that if your settings in solrconfig.xml do not prescribe using a separate schema.xml then it will default to using a managed-schema file.